# Faker.js Confusion

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, faker

So I want to do some testing with random fake data so I decided to get `faker.js`. I ran yarn add faker for my project and now I am very confused because the package downloaded doesn't seem to match the documentation [Here](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) at all. For example there is no `faker.js` or `faker.min.js` anywhere in the downloaded module? Can anyone give me some guidance on what I am missing here and how you actually load this in your app to use it? Alternatively if there is another good data faking library with more accurate documentation that would be good too. Thanks!

EDIT:[image]

Comment: Have a look under the examples folder - https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/tree/master/examples/browser/js

Comment: The source files are all there (see, for example, `node_modules/faker/lib`). You can import it into your project using `var faker = require('faker');` if using Node.js. Or you can download one of the built versions from https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/tree/master/build/build and include it in your file using <script> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it follows from Faker's `package.json` – `"main": "index.js"`. And `./node_modules/faker/index.js` has

```
var Faker = require('./lib');
var faker = new Faker({ locales: require('./lib/locales') });
module['exports'] = faker;
```

So, `faker` is on `./node_modules/faker/lib/index.js`. Go there... And there is a comment put in the beginning of the index file:

> this index.js file is used for including the faker library as a
>   CommonJS module, instead of a bundle ...
>
> you can also simply include the "faker.js" file which is the
>   auto-generated bundled version of the faker library
>
> ```
> var faker = require(./customAppPath/faker);
> var randomName = faker.name.findName();
> ```

I would not recommend to use Faker's [build](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/tree/master/build/build), it seems outdated. The better way to make a bundle by yourself... For example, Faker gives [gulp build option](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js#building-fakerjs) out-of-box.

Comment: This is right but seems ridiculous to me. So much simpler to just have a dist folder with the desired faker.js and faker.min.js files.

Comment: @NathanKamenar I love Faker, I even did [couple of commits](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/pull/482) last year... I agree, the doc is not pretty clear for Browser using. And I added to my answer a link to gulp build, maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: I have added an image to my post of the error I get when trying to run the build command. Think I might just save myself the hassle and direct download the minified js file and not use npm for this. Unfortunate because they made it so complicated it defeats the purpose of getting things through a package manager in the first place. Plain and simple, every npm package should come with a distribution ready js file.

Comment: @NathanKamenar Look, the feature you need is [already merged](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/pull/584) into Faker's 'master'. So the distributive files will be included into npm in the nearest release.